# Where does Windows Vista saves memory dump files when the previous dump file exists and the option "Overwrite any existing file" is unchecked?

Tags: windows-vista, memory, crash, dump

**Where does Windows Vista saves memory dump files after crash when the previous dump file exists and the option "Overwrite any existing file" is unchecked?**

As in the title, what happen and what does the system do when the configuration is as the mentioned above?

I think it may be not saved then, but a progress bar is displayed on 'blue screen' every time before the restart and it lasts some time as if duping were processing.

I found something like below, but how it would affect a free disk space if it doesn't save anything in this setting?

`"If there is a need to maintain multiple dumps of an issue, then you should uncheck the "Overwrite any existing file" box as well.  However, please remember that this may put a strain on free disk space over time."`
The source is https://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/01/08/understanding-crash-dump-files.aspx

It's really hard to understand how it works if it allows to set a dump option and won't do it because of the same name of file without any warning. What does this option exist for? Shouldn't it set off the dumping or just does it mean the same?

Comment: The same location.  If the option is unchecked the name of the file will contain the date.

Comment: @Ramhound , Are you sure? I can't see anthing like this in the same, right location. Do you have any source of this? Moreover, the definied name of file in textbox does not contain any variable part, is this the cause?

Comment: Its based on 15 years of experience dealing with Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound , thanks. Do you know why there is no the last memory dump file in the location although as far as I know it was saved? As I said above, it seemed to dump it somewhere (based on a progress bar).

Comment: You sure its not being created?  BlueScreenViewer will look in the correct location.

Comment: @Ramhound , thanks, it's very useful utility, but there is no crash that I'm looking for, all which are shown are very out of date - I can see the pre-previous one but not the last one. I don't know what's going on, it happend in the same moment as the last time during closing overloaded Chrome, actually I changed settings to dump full memory, not just some part, but I thought it should still work. After restart I couldn't see any information about the crash like wherre are helpful files and how to examine them as in the past. Anyway I saw the information that it's dumping and progress bar.

Comment: I've got just 1 GB of RAM in this machine and enough free space to keep such files likes memory dumps. Moreover I looked for it with file searcher and I can't see any appropriate files which would made today so I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just got done testing this in Windows 7. I've always used "overwrite". With "overwrite" I get multiple editions of the minidump files (names for the date and something incomprehensible) and just one memory.dmp in the usual place (because I don't override the path). The memory.dmp reflects the latest crash.

If a BSOD occurs with "overwrite..." unchecked and an already-existing memory.dmp, not only do I not get a new memory.dmp, I don't get a new minidump either! Even though they already have this mechanism for naming multiple instances of minidumps. That part was a surprise. But for the "real" dump (memory.dmp) it's always seemed to me that *not* checking "overwrite existing dump" meant "if there's already a memory.dmp, don't overwrite it with a new one". There was never any implication that a file of any other name would be created. And lo! none is.

So, there you go. You're not finding multiple memory.dmps because the system just isn't writing them. Looks like the technet article is wrong. (Wouldn't be the first time.)